# Event-sourcing with akka-persistance: growing state as list?

Tags: scala, akka, cqrs, event-sourcing, akka-persistence

I am designing a backend using CQRS + Event sourcing, using Akka + Scala. I am not sure about how to handle a growing state. For instance, I will have a growing list of users. To my understanding, each user will be created following a UserCreated event, such events will be replayed by the PersistentActor, and the users will be stored in a collection. Something like:

```
class UsersActor extends PersistentActor {

    override def persistenceId = ....

    private case class UsersState(users: List[User])

    private var state = UsersState()

    ....
}
```

Obviously such state would eventually grow too big to be held in memory by this actor, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

I found [this](https://github.com/ScalaConsultants/akka-persistence-eventsourcing) example project: the idea seems that each user should be held by a different actor, and loaded (from the event history) as needed.

What is the right way to do this? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Event sourcing isn't appropriate for all parts of the application.. do you need the list of all users in order to query it to let users log in or out?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jazmit - no, I don't need to have all users "present" at once. I am studying the project I linked, it seems to only "inflate" the item it needs in order to serve or update it. Do you have further hints?

Comment: Yes, but the seed project uses one persistent actor per user.. still not sure what exactly you're after, the only thing I can think to say is not to design domain actors with ever-growing state..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: each aggregate/entity (in my example, each User) gets its own actor, which embeds the state for that particular entity and that one only.

Comment: +1. Not the place for discussion, but do you modify behavior depending on state of `PersistentActor`? I.e. if event called `UserCreated` gets persisted, do you modify behavior so that only i.e. `UserRemoved` and `UserUpdated` events can be persisted? Or i.e. if `UserRemoved` event gets persisted that none of other events cannot be persisted anymore for an actor with that specific persistence id.

Comment: Indeed, that's what I'm doing: modify behavior according to state.

Comment: Candy for you. Thanks for a quick answer. :)

Comment: Solution seems reasonable, but how do you obtain i.e. all `User` actors?

Comment: @BranislavLazic - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43375781/how-to-fetch-all-persisted-entities)